# $watch to check varible defined in the scope AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-watch

I have the following directive to show alerts, so I want catch when the show varible change to star run a timeout how I can do that?

the link function was invoked only the first time but all variable show, message and type was undefined

Directive code

```
 angular.module('pysFormWebApp')      
    .directive('alertDirective', 

    function  alertDirective ($timeout) {   
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {
            message : "=",
            type : "=",
            show : "=",
            test : "="
        },
        controller : function ($scope) {

            $scope.closeAlert = function () {
                $scope.show = false;
                $scope.type = "alert alert-dismissable alert-";
                $scope.message = "";
            };

            $scope.getStrongMessage = function (type) {
                var strongMessage = "";
                if(type == "success"){
                    strongMessage = "\xC9xito ! ";
                } else if(type == "warning"){
                    strongMessage = "Cuidado ! ";
                return strongMessage;
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(scope.show, 
             function (newValue) {
             console.log(newValue); 
             },true);
        },
        templateUrl : "views/utilities/alert.html"
    };
});
```

html directive code

```
<div ng-show="show">
    <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-{{type}}">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="closeAlert()">&times;</button>
        <strong>{{getStrongMessage(type)}}</strong> {{  message | translate }} 
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller example

```
  $scope.info.alert = {
    message: "EXPOTED-SUCCESS",
    type: "success",
    show : true
  };
```

html code

```
<alert-directive  message="info.alert.message" 
          type="info.alert.type" 
          show="info.alert.show">
</alert-directive>
```

Comment: You have wrong watch code, it should be `scope.$watch('show'` inside your directive

Comment: thanks so much @PankajParkar I spend so much time in this error.  you are right it was the error

Comment: I think that is better for future references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have make mistake while setting watch on the scope variable. Basically `$watch` takes 1st parameter as `string`/`function` which gets evaluated on each digest cycle & 2nd parameter would be the callback function

```
//replaced `scope.show` by `'show'` 
scope.$watch('show', function (newValue) {
   console.log(newValue); 
},true);
```